# Elasticsearch http.max_content_length when compressed

Tags: elasticsearch

How does compression affects the

`http.max_content_length`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules

Let's say the content is 130Mb but when compressed it's 80Mb. Will the elastic search reject the content because uncompressed size is over the default 100Mb?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `http.max_content_length` parameter applies to the uncompressed size and defaults to 100 MB.

The best way is to try it out:

Test 1: Set `http.compression: false` and `http.max_content_length: 100mb`, then send a JSON body that is larger than 100mb

=> You'll get `413 Request Entity Too Large`

Test 2: Set `http.compression: true` and `http.max_content_length: 100mb`, then send a JSON body whose uncompressed size is larger than 100mb but smaller than 100mb when gzipped

=> You'll get `413 Request Entity Too Large`

Comment: where do I set these properties, In elastic search config?

Comment: @SJ1 yes, in the `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file